# How to send an email notification when PowerShell script gets an error?

Tags: powershell, email

I have a PS script that works automatically on task scheduler, at the end of the script there is an email confirming that the script was successful, if the script gets one error during its process the script stops ($ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"), this avoids the script to get to the point when the confirmation email is sent. But, I cant send an email when there is an error to notify someone about this error.

What can be a solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you are using `Send-MailMessage`. Update your question with a mimimal example you are trying to make work. Questions without code go to https://superuser.com/

Comment: don't use `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` for the _entire script_. [*grin*] instead, wrap the various parts in `try/catch` blocks and - when one of those catch blocks is triggered - then send you failure mail, and _then_ exit the script.